# Approximation of growth of a function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to learn about analysis of algorithms, but I find running times a little bit hard to understand. I have a problem where I am supposed to find the exact approximation of the growth of a function and the big-O notation.

I am wondering if the order of growth of D is N, because function D is only executing step() at most n times?

I have the function

```java
void step() {
        count++;
    }
void functionD(int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            step();
        }
        else
            step();
    }
```

Comment: Both branches of `if` contain the same action: `step()`. That's why we can *simplify* the initial code into `void functionD(int n) {step();}`. So far so good `functionD` *ignores* `n` and increment `count` *once* which has `O(1)` time complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've made a *typo*, since your claim

> because `functionD` is only executing `step()` at *most* `n` times?

sounds strange. Just have look. *Both* `if` branches *do the same*:

```
void functionD(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {  // either n is even 
        step();        //   ... do the step()
    }                  
    else               // or n is odd
        step();        //   ... do exactly the same - step()
}
```

so we can simplify the code into

```
void functionD(int n) {
    // either n is even or odd do the step; 
    step();
}
```

Now, since `step` does nothing but increment a `conter`

```
void step() {
    count++;
}
```

`functionD` increments a `counter` and that's all:

```
void functionD(int n) {
    count++;
}
```

Finally, we have for `functionD`: ignore `n`, increment a `counter`, this operation has evident `O(1)` time complexity (`functionD` *ignores* `n`).

Answer (score 0):

Since the body of the if statement is the same as the body of the else statement, the step function will always be executed.

Since there is no kind of loop or recursion, the algorithm runs in constant time.